# Web API that takes in a complex type and returns a complex type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

What is the official MS or best architecture practice for designing a Web API that takes in a complex type and returns a complex type?

Difficulty:
        Passing complex types over HTTP without a reference to a central data type while staying RESTful.

Currently:
    I am doing this successfully, but arguing with my boss about the best practice and if I have done this correctly.  Microsoft claims you can pass in a complex type just like a parameter with a [FromBody] attribute but I haven't had any luck with this(a working example with a complex type would be wonderful).

Type Model Knowledge:
    The client application and Web API both have a reference to a central library that contains a class.  My boss doesn't like this as we will have different compilations of the library DLL(from one client application to the next), the only way I can see around this is to use WSDL to pass the type information on each request(not ideal for mobile in remote locations, hence REST), any suggestions.

Current Code(working):

Controller Calling API

```
[Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
            InstallerPinModel currentInstaller = new InstallerPinModel();
            currentInstaller.userName = "from Controller";
            Task<WebResponse> response = checkPinTime(currentInstaller);//checkPinTime calls API

            //I found the following two lines are very helpful for debugging
            //while(response.IsCompleted == false)
                //Thread.Sleep(100);

            Stream responseResultsStream = response.Result.GetResponseStream();
            int responseResultContentLength = (int)response.Result.ContentLength;
            byte[] responseResultContentAsBytes = new byte[responseResultContentLength];
            responseResultsStream.Read(responseResultContentAsBytes, 0, responseResultContentLength);//Pull Data Stream into Byte[] responseResultContentAsBytes
            string responseResultsAsString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseResultContentAsBytes);
            JavaScriptSerializer serializesJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            currentInstaller = serializesJS.Deserialize<InstallerPinModel>(responseResultsAsString);
            if(currentInstaller.userName == "from API")
                returnView = GoalView;
            else
                returnView = TimedOutView;
        }
        return View();
    }

public  Task<WebResponse> checkPinTime(InstallerPinModel incomingUser)//Function to call Post Web API
    {   
        string requestData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(incomingUser);//Just slightly different syntax
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] requestDataAsBytes = encoding.GetBytes(requestData);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:51366/api/InstallerPin");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = requestDataAsBytes.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Stream requestDataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestDataStream.Write(requestDataAsBytes, 0, requestDataAsBytes.Length);
        requestDataStream.Close();
        Task<WebResponse> response = request.GetResponseAsync();
        return response;
    }
```

Web API

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        //ReadIncoming
        InstallerPinModel incomingInstallerPIN = new InstallerPinModel();
        Task<byte[]> requestContentByteArray = Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string requestContentAsString = encoding.GetString(await requestContentByteArray);
        JavaScriptSerializer serializesJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        incomingInstallerPIN = serializesJS.Deserialize<InstallerPinModel>(requestContentAsString);

        //This is where the post would take place
        //Send Responspe Object
        InstallerPinModel outgoingInstallerPIN = new InstallerPinModel();
        outgoingInstallerPIN = incomingInstallerPIN;
        outgoingInstallerPIN.userName = "from API";


        //BuildOutgoing
        string responseAsString = serializesJS.Serialize(outgoingInstallerPIN);
        StringContent responseContent = new StringContent(responseAsString);
        await responseContent.LoadIntoBufferAsync();
        HttpResponseMessage returnableResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
        returnableResponseMessage.Content = responseContent;
        return returnableResponseMessage;
    }
```

Routing

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "noParamsInURL",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { }
        );//Route for InstallerPinController

        //(Default) Route for standard API Controllers
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{application}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, application = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Type Model

```
public class InstallerPinModel
{
    public string userName {get; set;}
    public int pin {get; set;}
    public int newPin { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure to include references to Type Model in both the API and Client Application.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the official MS or best architecture practice for designing a
>   Web API that takes in a complex type and returns a complex type?

Web API services are REST web services. There are a set of REST principles. Following links below will help you to understand them

1. Article about Richardson Maturity Model from Martin Fowler http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html
2. Video presentation from Oslo NDC about REST principles http://vimeo.com/43808786

ASP.NET Web API is only one of technologies with help of which you can implement REST services
More about features and best practices are in presentation from Build 2013 conference about ASP.NET Web API http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-504

> Difficulty: Passing complex types over HTTP without a reference to a
>   central data type while staying RESTful
>   According to principles above do following:

1. Use different HTTP Verbs and media types. Most widely used GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. They are perfectly mapping to CRUD operations. GET = read, POST = create, PUT = update, DELETE.
2. Verbs are restricting you in way how to pass complex data. All verbs except GET are using HTTP message body, HTTP message body is not allowed in GET according to HTTP standard. It is not a problem to get complex data type from server in body for example in form of serialized JSON string, for requests except GET it is also not a problem to use JSON for complex types in body
3. When you are dealing with GET and have no chance to pass complex data type as JSON string in HTTP message body - you need carefully according to REST design your URLs. For example I has User resource I want to get user  I have no other way as to pass this data either using HTTP Headers or through URL string. Then use identifier for you resources. To get this user I will pass it through URL http://myapp.com/users/179067, where 179067 identifier for user resource, it could be user Id in DB or some Id mapped to user that identifies it uniquely.

Or another one sample. I need to get user that was created before 2000 year and user from Germany. This example is similar to query and I will use [ODATA](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/) syntax - [http://myapp.com/users?$filter=Country eq 'germany' and Created le 01.01.200](http://myapp.com/users?%24filter=Country%20eq%20%27germany%27%20and%20Created%20le%2001.01.200). Do not afraid about spaces or quotes, they will be encoded as %20 or %27

AND WHEN you need WSDL or trying to reinvent WSDL then may be REST is not for you. Then use anz other WS-*/SOAP technology, e.g. WCF